# Client Socket Programming: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java

I am trying to get the host address by passing host name. But while running my code, I get the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at socketprogram_client.SocketProgram_Client.main(SocketProgram_Client.java:16)
 Java Result: 1
```

Can anyone please tell me why I am getting this error?

Here is my code:

```
package socketprogram_client;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class SocketProgram_Client 
{
public static void main ( String args[] ) throws IOException 
{
    String host_name = args[0];

    try
    {
        InetAddress my_ipaddr = InetAddress.getByName(host_name);
        System.out.println("Resolved to IP address: " + my_ipaddr.getHostAddress());
    }
    catch ( UnknownHostException e )
    {
        System.out.println("Could not find IP address for: " + host_name);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Did you pass anything into your application?

Comment: Well, the moment I run it, the above exception is shown. so, no, I was unable to pass any argument.

Comment: Passing arguments is not an interactive business. You pass them on the command line where you start the program.

Comment: The program is looking for an argument in args[0] and not finding anything. You need to pass in at least one argument or you will continue to receive this error.

Comment: The problem in your code is nothing to do with client programming. You may help other people if you choose a suitable title for your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some other languages allow you to retrieve the name of the program being executed as the first argument in the array (i.e. args[0]) and any additional arguments being passed to the program are referenced as args[1], args[2], etc.

Not so with Java. args[0] in Java is always the first argument you have passed it, and the array will be empty if you have passed no arguments

Example with no arguments and args.length == 0

```
java -cp . SocketProgram_Client
```

Example with one argument and args.length == 1, and args[0] == "arg1"

```
java -cp . SocketProgram_Client arg1
```